# Azure Ad: Why is ipaddr in optionalClaims not provided to client?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

I have added the follwing in the manifest for my App in Azure AD:

```
"optionalClaims": {
        "idToken": [
            {
                "name": "ipaddr",
                "source": null,
                "essential": false,
                "additionalProperties": []
            }, ...
```

But when getting the claims for the authenticated user this one is not provided. Others like auth_time work. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: As per Razis comment, the application registration options here do not apply to the B2C token issuer, only to the AAD token issuer.

Answer (score 0):

Like to confirm -- Do you want b2c to return IpAddress claim back to the app in the id_token?

Comment: You can use a claim resolver {Context:IPAddress} within a custom policy to send the IPAddress back:
             <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="IPAddress" DefaultValue="{Context:IPAddress}" >
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview

Comment: is there a way to do this for the "sid" claim? I don't see it as an option in that documentation and don't want to go through all the trouble of making a custom policy if not possible